# validar un formulario con php

Tags: php

cuando cambio el action ya a una direccion real no muestra el mesaje

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
        <title>Validar Datos con PHP</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="#"  method="POST" class="formulario" autocomplete="off">
        <h1>LOGIN</h1>
            <input type="text" placeholder="ingrese el correo" class="correo" name="correo" >
            <input type="text" placeholder="ingrese el password" class="password" name="password">
            <input type="submit" value="Enviar" name="enviar" class="btn">
            <?php
                include("recibi.php");
            ?>
        </form>
    </body>
    </html>
        <?php
                    if(isset($_POST['enviar'])){
                        $correo = $_POST['correo'];
                        $pass = $_POST['password'];
                        $mesajes = array();
                        if($correo == ""){
                            array_push($mesajes,"no se ingreso correo");
                        }
                        if($pass == ""){
                            array_push($mesajes,"no se ingreso password");
                        }
                        $valor = 1;
                        if(count($mesajes)>0){
                            for($i=0; $i<count($mesajes); $i++){
                                echo "<p class='error'>".$mesajes[$i]."</p>";
                            }
        
                        }else{
                            echo "<p class='correcto'>datos correctos</p>";
                        }
                    }
                ?>
```

Comment: Esto se basa en una suposición, pero si lo que quieres es que se ejecute el archivo `recibi.php` al pulsar el botón enviar, debes ponerlo en el action de `<form>` y no como un include 

La linea quedaría así:
    
`<form action="recibi.php"  method="POST" class="formulario" autocomplete="off">`

Si esto no soluciona tu pregunta, o no se ajusta a lo que buscas, por favor, edita la pregunta para proporcionar más detalles y/o contexto para que sepamos cómo ayudar.

Answer (score 0):

Vamos a ver. Te sobra el include.
Supongamos que la página que muestras en la pregunta se llama formulario.php pues bien por la forma que tiene como mínimo necesita poner en form action la dirección de este archivo

```
<form action="formulario.php" method="POST" ...
```

O bien

```
<from action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="POST"
```

Además coloca el código php donde compruebas las variables antes que el formulario, para que sea lo primero que se ejecute.
Básicamente y por lo que entiendo de tu pregunta este es el camino a seguir, luego estaría si quieres que el form se muestre siempre o solo en caso de error y detalles así.